# how to find slope of discrete point?

Tags: vector-analysis, angle, slope

I am wondering if it is possible to find the slope at each point in the following dataset,

`%  X       Y
%===================
0.7761  0.5715
0.794   0.5729
0.8117  0.5744
0.8292  0.5762
0.8465  0.5782
0.8637  0.5804
0.8807  0.5828
0.8977  0.5853
0.9144  0.5879
0.9311  0.5907
0.9477  0.5937
0.9641  0.5968
0.9805  0.6
0.9967  0.6033
1.0129  0.6067`

I understand that the slope can be obtained using the difference of the two neighboring points by

$$m = \frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$$

and, the angle that each point made with the $x$-axis is essentially the $atan$ of $m$

$$\theta = \tan^{-1}(m) $$

But, is it possible to calculate the slope without using the above formula? without trying to curve-fit the points.

Comment: The formula that you're using for the slope $m$ assumes that the function $y=f(x)$ is linear between the points. There are other methods, too. It's possible to assume a quadratic relation, etc ... But why do you ask if it's possible to calculate without using the formula? What's wrong with using the formula?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the formula. The reason is that the method is heavily dependent on the sampling rate of the points. I am curious if there is any other method or approach that can be used.

Comment: @BeeTiau: I'd take Matti P's suggestion, and assume a reasonable polynomial shape (why polynomial? Because they're super-easy to differentiate), differentiate that, and get the derivative value at the desired points. This method has the advantage of smoothing out your data a bit (fitting a curve is a summation process, and hence smoothing, whereas raw differentiation like you did makes graphs more jagged and noisy). As for sampling rate, fitting a reasonable polynomial (you might look up cubic splines) will mitigate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience,
when trying to estimate the slope at a point,
it is better to use the slope of the line
between the preceding and following point.

This is analogous to the fact that
$f'(x)$
is more accurately estimated by
$(f(x+h)-f(x-h))/(2h)$
(error of order $h^2$)
than by
$(f(x+h)-f(x))/(h)$
(error of order $h$).

Comment: Thanks. Meaning that there is no way we can estimate the slope without knowing the functions (or trend?) of the data?

Comment: All you need are a series of (x, y) values.